# How to Write a single byte to a file in C++, while keeping the rest of the file unchanged

Tags: c++

I want to overwrite a byte in a file with a different byte. When I do this it replaces all bytes before and after with blank spaces "when viewed in notepad."

My question is how do I change a byte value in a file without changing the other bytes in the file.

Thanks for your time.

Here is my code...

```
#include "math.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("file.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::beg);
    fout.seekp(10);

    int a = 0x21;
    fout.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));

    fout.close();


    return 0;
}
```

This will write a "!" to the 10th spot/address in a file. However it does not preserve the other data(bytes) in the file. Thye are deleted with blank spaces in notepad.

EDIT

walnut's suggestion worked! My question about that is what is the difference between using the open flags "ios" and ""ios_base"?
Thanks.

Below is the working program. Edits a file and writes a "!" to it while preserving the other byte values before and after the written byte.

```
#include "math.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("file.bin", ios_base::out | ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    fout.seekp(5);

    int a = 0x7B5C;
    fout.write((char*)&a, 2);
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in what way your code doesn't work.

Comment: Lets say I want to write a value to the middle of a file. When I do that with the code I posted it overwrites the data that comes before and after.

Comment: In standard C++, you cannot.   A common technique is to create a second file, copy contents of the first to the second with any changes needed, then delete the original, and move/rename the new file to be the original.    However, most reasonably capable and modern operating systems do support some (platform specific) means to do it directly.   The reason standard C++ doesn't support this is that quite a few real-world platforms (or disk formats) do not.

Comment: @Peter: "*In standard C++, you cannot.*" Since when? Where does iostreams or fwrite prevent you from writing to a specific location in the middle of the file?

Comment: @NicolBolas there is no way to *insert* content at the beginning or in the middle while *preserving* existing content. New content can only *overwrite* existing content, or be *appended* at the end.

Comment: Hi, sorry i'm new here.why was it closed?

Comment: @Cyclone Given that there is no close reason stated in the close banner, I assume that the three of us who voted to close were not agreeing on the reason. I personally voted to close because questions asking for debugging help should include example input, the output it generates and the expected output, which is what I hinted at with my first comment. I hadn't noticed your answer to that. You should [edit] your question to include the information that you stated in your comment and even better would be short example file before and after running the program.

Comment: I have voted to reopen for now (two more are necessary), assuming you will add the contents of your comment to the question. Btw. I think that the answer so far overlooked another bug in your program. In particular the open flags `ios::binary | ios::out | ios::beg` are not correct. You probably want `ios_base::out | ios_base::in | ios_base::binary`. `ios::beg` isn't an open mode at all.

Comment: Thanks walnut. Your suggestion worked. what was the difference between "ios" and "ios_base?"
Thanks again!

I added more detail to my above question. Hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem here is that you're writing an `int`, not a "byte". You're writing `sizeof(int)` bytes to the file, not just one. If you want to overwrite a byte in a file with a different byte, then you have to write a *single* byte:

```
fout.seekp(location_to_overwrite);
fout.put(0x21);
```

If you're trying to *insert* one or more bytes into the middle of the file, thus causing the file to become longer, you can't do that. You instead have to do something else, like writing a new file that contains the first part of the old file, the stuff you're inserting, followed by the rest of the old file. Or else just load the rest of the old file into memory, truncate the old file to the place you want to insert, and then append your new data followed by the old data. Though the latter requires being able to read all of the file into memory.

Comment: The file that I'm using is not going to change in size. I just want to change a byte/int or what ever in a file to a different value. I can do this using a HEX editor but I wanted to do it in C++.
Thanks!

Comment: @Cyclone that is easily doable, as Nicol's example shows.

Comment: After the write, seek to the end of the file before closing it.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

#include "math.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
 ofstream fout;
 fout.open("file.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::beg);
 fout.seekp(0x0f);
 fout.put(0x21);
 fout.close();


 return 0;
}

Comment: @Cyclone: Saying that it "doesn't work" isn't useful. How are you verifying that it doesn't work? What file are you using? What is happening to the file when you run the code?

Comment: Sorry. I will try to explain.
I created a file and opened it in notepad. I typed in something like this
"000000000000"
I wanted to change the 0 in the middle Just as an example.
When I run the program it writes the new byte in the correct location but now the zeros in the file are gone and replaced with emmty spaces before and after.